# MySQL complex select with time aggregation

Tags: mysql, select, sum, aggregate-functions

schema in SQL-Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/359c8/1

What I try to do is getting all persons, the time spend (hh:mm) on a project like this:

```
Date       | Project     | Persons                        | Total Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------
25.11.2013 | Project One | Jane Doe hh:mm, John Doe hh:mm | Total hh:mm
26.11.2013 | Project One | Jane Doe hh:mm, John Doe hh:mm | Total hh:mm
27.11.2013 | Project One | Jane Doe hh:mm, John Doe hh:mm | Total hh:mm
28.11.2013 | Project Four| Jane Doe hh:mm, John Doe hh:mm | Total hh:mm
```

I have really no idea how to get this output especially the comma sepertated  part.

Hope someone had or has a similar issue to help me finding a solution.

Comment: Can you explain the column meanings? Specifically, which column is the PROJECT,how is the TOTAL TIME calculated and where that time value to the right of the person's name comes from.

Comment: column names are not same in fiddle what is von, where is Project, Date?

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated the fiddle here [link to new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65f3c/1).
ProjectStart and ProjectEnd are always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65f3c/15)

Based on your data - I believe you need to start by summarizing how much each person does per project per day. (You had one example where John Doe worked twice on one day). That solution would be *(the workunits column was just to know if one person at more than one record per day per project)*:

```
SELECT `date`, projectstart, person, COUNT(*) as workunits
      , SUM(TIMEDIFF(CAST(end AS time), CAST(begin AS time))) AS worked
FROM IMPORT
GROUP BY `date`, projectstart, person;
```

Then to get your final result, you need to summarize that for each project per day

```
SELECT `date`, projectstart
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(person,' ',CAST(worked AS time))) AS people
     , SUM(worked) AS worked
FROM (SELECT `date`, projectstart, person, COUNT(*) as workunits
             , SUM(TIMEDIFF(CAST(end AS time), CAST(begin AS time))) AS worked
      FROM IMPORT
      GROUP BY `date`, projectstart, person) AS t
GROUP BY `date`, projectstart;
```